# ¿Cómo crear un LOG de actividad de usuarios en JAVA?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Hola buenas noches estimados amigos informáticos, tengo un problema y estaría muy agradecido que me dieran una mano. El planteamiento es el siguiente: Actualmente estoy desarrollando una aplicacion de escritorio en JAVA, pensando el dia de ayer en algo mas para agregarle al sistema, se me ocurrió el crear un especie de "log" o "registro" de las actividades que realicen los usuarios del sistema para verificar que usuario ha realizado cambios (para bien o para mal) en el sistema, he visto por la web informacion sobre Log4J mas no parece ser lo que necesito. Estaría más que agradecido con todos por la ayuda que me puedan brindar,sin embargo hago mi esfuerzo antes de acudir a la comunidad por una mano. Muchas gracias a todos por tomarse su tiempo y gracias por compartir su conocimiento con todos! Saludos!

Comment: Esta pregunta es muy amplia. Se basa en opiniones. Lo ideal es que plantees un problema específico. Trata de reformularla o plantea un problema claro. En todo caso, sin saber de qué va tu proyecto, hay muchas formas de hacer lo que quieres. Necesitas además una forma de persistir los datos del `log` bien sea en archivo, base de datos o algo por el estilo, y para eso hay muchas opciones y opiniones diferentes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su sugerencia compañero. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

con log4j puedes crear un sistema de logs en Java perfectamente. ¿Por qué comentas que no lo necesitas? Podrías crear un log formateado con un estilo parecido a este:

```
Fecha y Hora | Usuario | Actividad | Otros
```

Investiga sobre como utilizar `logstash`, que es una herramienta para la administración de logs (https://www.elastic.co/es/products/logstash). Si te montas un sistema logstash que lea de tu archivo de logs tendrás la información perfectamente organizada y será muy sencillo de consultar.

Un saludo y espero que te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias compañero investigare un poco mas! Saludos!